# playframework call Model method from view javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, crud, playframework-2.0

Like in play tutorial for the Tags Set (customize crud field); i want to add a new functionality when user selects a tag then javascript should get current user (models.user) and call a method user.doSomething(). is this possible to do in a CRUD custom field ? (like in tutorial for yabe tags?).

is there a way I can make a custom CRUD field as a list of checkboxes and when user check some checkboxes then i should write code (maybe javascript) that gets current logged in user and then call a method on that user Model?

thanks.

Comment: it will be very simple for you to create your own form than using the one generated by crud...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example from the play tutorial (customize crud field). i suppose that you want to execute an action when a tag is clicked. that can be done simply as shown below

```
#{crud.form}
    #{crud.custom 'tags'}
        <label for="tags">
            &{'tags'}
        </label>
        (...)
        <div class="tags-list">
            #{list items:models.Tag.findAll(), as:'tag'}
               <span id="${tag.id}" onclick="toggle(this)" class="tag ${object.tags.contains(tag) ? 'selected' : ''}">
                     /**** ADD An ACTION CALL HERE ******/
                    <a href="@{Application.getConnected().doSomething()}">${tag}</a>
                     /**** END *****/
               </span> 
               <input id="h${tag.id}" type="hidden" name="${fieldName}" 
                        value="${object.tags.contains(tag) ? tag.id : ''}" />
            #{/list}
        </div>
    #{/crud.custom}
#{/crud.form}
```

you have to implement the method getConnected() by your self in you controller (maybe Application.java). supposing that you use the **Secure Module** it will be something like

```
void getConnected(){ 
        if(Security.isConnected()) {
            User user = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();
            renderArgs.put("user", user);
        }

}
```

Comment: thank you ; i'll give it a try and let you know if it works. i noticed how you wrapp the tag name inside a href and point it to `@{User.getConnected().doSomething()}` . seems a clever workaround. i'll try to see if this works

Comment: itried it but got this error : `No route found (In {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/form.html around line 37)
No route able to invoke action User.getConnected was found.`                                                                it seems i need to add a route for the model user ? how can we do this? it is unable to detect `User.getConnected()`

Comment: you have to implement the method by your self. i updated my answer, have a look..

Comment: It still gives this error No route found (In {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/form.html around line 37)
No route able to invoke action User.getConnected was found.
i need to implement a controller action method and call it instead of a method in the models.User . i don't think calling a models.user method will work. it must be a controller action method with route defined.

Comment: So the workaround that works for me: is to implement a `controllers.Users.dosomething()` action method. make this method last call `renderJSON(user)`. add url map to route file. then in javascript make the call to `Users.dosomething()`. and better use jquery `$.get(url, function(data)` to make it an ajax call